# how to limit max key size in redis

Tags: redis

Is there a config option in redis where I can specify redis key **should not be greater than 10 MB.** If an application logic tries to insert a key greater than 10 MB redis should ignore it.

I know the current limit is 512 MB but the whole thing gets slowed down if a huge key gets inserted.

Comment: There's no way to do that. Unless you modify Redis source code and recompile it. Or disable all write commands and implement your own version with Lua script or Redis module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert at Redis configuration but after seeing this post made some search on `redis.conf` file to see is there any config that may help.

According to the [configuration](http://mirrors.slickstack.io/redis/redis-conf-4.0.9.txt) there is an option called `proto-max-bulk-len` which is set to `512MB`

> In the Redis protocol, bulk requests, that are, elements representing single
> strings, are normally limited ot 512 mb. However you can change this limit here.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get proto-max-bulk-len
1) "proto-max-bulk-len"
2) "536870912"
```

According to the [this commit](https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/4633), it is restricted to `1 mb`. The author(same name and profile photo) of this commit also replied to a similar question in [here](https://groups.google.com/g/redis-db/c/HH4z-8mHNLM). So it may help.

Comment: IMHO, that config only limit the size of a single command. User can still use lots of `APPEND` command to create a key whose value is larger than 1MB.

Comment: @for_stack thank you for the comment, you may be right. That could be the closest/existing command to limit it but not exactly a solution.

Comment: @esroy This looks very promising. I will try it and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: It indeed does what I asked for but does not help the root cause which was out of scope of this question. accepting answer.